# Type Definitions for sub components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I have defined sub-components to my styled component, and am trying to provide type definitions for it - TSC complains 'Property 'PrimaryText' does not exist on type 'StyledComponentClass'. Similarly for 'SubText'.

```
export const Tab = styled(NavLink)`
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 119, 204, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 0 2px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 60px;
    min-width: 125px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
`;

Tab.PrimaryText = styled(Box)`
    height: 22px;
    color: #3d464d;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 22px;
`;

Tab.SubText = styled(Box)`
    height: 15px;
    color: #525d66;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 15px;
`;
```

How do I go about specifying the types? Looked around a lot. There's hardly any reference.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve by doing this? There are some convoluted ways you could use to create a merged type but it really doesn't seem worth it.

Would something like this not be an option? The only difference being the usage of the `Tab` style is now `Tab.Main` (or whatever you call it) instead.

```
export const Tab = {
  Main: styled(NavLink)`
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 119, 204, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 0 2px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 60px;
    min-width: 125px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
  `,
  PrimaryText: styled(Box)`
    height: 22px;
    color: #3d464d;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 22px;
  `,
  SubText: styled(Box)`
    height: 15px;
    color: #525d66;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 15px;
  `,
};
```